# Python login to web page not working

Tags: python, python-requests

Pretty new to Python and I'm trying to make a program that will log into a website and get the html contents of it:

Here is the form that I'm trying to fill in:

```
 <form method="post" action="loginDo.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="LoginStamp" value="238a72c6 a127479c bf6ceb84 188367fc cf9065e5 454c5868 59ffd5f2 3a144648 33690673" />
  <table>
    <tr><td>Schoolafkorting:</td><td><input type="text" size="30" name="Root" value="" onblur="verifySchool()" ID="School" /></td><td ID="Schoolname"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Gebruikersnaam of e-mail:</td><td><input type="text" size="30" name="Username" value=""/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Wachtwoord:</td><td><input type="password" size="30" name="Password"/></td></tr>
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript">verifySchool ();</script>
  <input type="submit" alt="inloggen" value="Log in" name="Login" />
</form>
```

And here is my python code:

```
from requests import session

payload = {
'Root': 'testRoot',
'Username': 'test',
'Password': 'testpass'
}

with session() as c:
  r = c.post('http://rapport.myro.be/login.php', data=payload)
  print(r.text)
```

And the result of this code is:

```
<tr><td>Schoolafkorting:</td><td><input type="text" size="30" name="Root" value="" onblur="verifySchool()" ID="School" /></td><td ID="Schoolname"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Gebruikersnaam of e-mail:</td><td><input type="text" size="30" name="Username" value="test"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Wachtwoord:</td><td><input type="password" size="30" name="Password"/></td></tr>
```

As you can see, the "Username" Value gets filled in with "test" however the "Root" and "Password" Fields remain blank.

Since "Password" doesn't have a value atribute I can see why it might not work but "Root" does have one and it also remains blank so the only thing getting filled in is Username

Can anyone help me with this (I'm using python 2.7)?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the link?

Answer (score 2):

The request should be made to the **target** of the form.

You can see the target here: `<form method="post" action="loginDo.php">`

So, the correct code to send the POST request is: `c.post('http://rapport.myro.be/loginDo.php', data=payload)`

You may also need to provide a `LoginStamp`, depending on the website.

Comment: Ok That seems to do something however I get "Invalid Referrer" (I also tried providing a loginstamp but that didn't seem to make a difference)

Comment: Then you need to set a referer. It is likely the website expects the form as the referer, so: `requests.post(…, headers={'Referer': 'http://rapport.myro.be/login.php'})`.