# Android Java jsoup post incorrect password

Tags: php, android

I'm creating an application that logs in to the following website > "http://rapport.myro.be/login.php"

I have this code right now:

```
try {
            final Document htmlDoc;
            String strURL = "http://rapport.myro.be/loginDo.php";
            htmlDoc = Jsoup.connect(strURL)
                    .referrer("http://rapport.myro.be/login.php")
                    .data("Root", "KSH")
                    .data("Username", "user")
                    .data("Password", "pass")
                    .post();




            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   print(htmlDoc.toString());

                }
            });



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And it doesn't work... the website returns me to the login page with the error "LoginCode" I'm sure the username and password is correct.

If I set the url to "login.php" and replace .post(); with get(); it shows me that it fills in the Username box but not the Password box as it doesn't have a value but this shouldn't be a problem as I'm bypassing the login.php page and going through the loginDo.php page.

I've had similar problems with python ([Python login to web page not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094175/python-login-to-web-page-not-working)) and I've managed to fix those but it doesn't work here for some reason.

Maybe it always gives this error and just sends you over to the index page (after login), if that's the case, how can I set the htmlDoc to the new url ("http://rapport.myro.be/index.php") without losing the current open session?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just use the browser log a bit, suggesting that "UnknownUser".